# Galería en html y cc, error en clases

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy intentando diseñar una galería de imágenes solo con html y css, sin utilizar ningún plugin, el proyecto debe funcionar de la siguiente manera, se deben mostrar las imágenes en el navegador y al momento de seleccionar una de estas, se debe ampliar en una ventana modal la imagen que se ha seleccionado, esta galeria tiene tres tipos de controles, he colocado < para ir a la anteiro imagen y > para ir  a la siguiente, el caso es que las clases y estilos que estoy aplicando no se aplican a la galería como resultado lo único que obtengo es una imagen tipo enlace pero no con las medidas ni los etilos que estoy aplicando, ya revise cada una de las etiquetas html y el css y no encuentro el error, la estructura de las carperas es la siguiente, una carpeta raiz llamada galeria y dentro de esta una carpeta llamada css para el archivo .css, una llamada imágenes para la imagenes .JPG y un archivo index .html, espero la ayuda de esta comunidad. Mil gracias.

````
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Galeria</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Galeria de Imagenes</h1>
    <ul class="galeria">
        <li><a href="#img1"><img src="imagenes/img1.jpg"></a> </li>
        <li><a href="#img2"><img src="imagenes/img2.jpg"></a> </li>
        <li><a href="#img3"><img src="imagenes/img3.jpg"></a> </li>
        <li><a href="#img4"><img src="imagenes/img4.jpg"></a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="modal" id="img1">
        <h3>Paisaje 1</h3>
        <div class="imagen">
            <a href="#img4">&#60;<</a>
            <a href="#img2"><img src="imagenes/img1.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#img2">></a>
            
        </div>
        <a class="cerrar" href="">X</a>
    </div>

        <div class="modal" id="img2">
        <h3>Paisaje 1</h3>
        <div class="imagen">
            <a href="#img1">&#60;<</a>
            <a href="#img3"><img src="imagenes/img2.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#img3">></a>
            
        </div>
        <a class="cerrar" href="">X</a>
    </div>

        <div class="modal" id="img3">
        <h3>Paisaje 3</h3>
        <div class="imagen">
            <a href="#img4">&#60;<</a>
            <a href="#img2"><img src="imagenes/img1.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#img2">></a>
            
        </div>
        <a class="cerrar" href="">X</a>
    </div>

        <div class="modal" id="img4">
        <h3>Paisaje 4</h3>
        <div class="imagen">
            <a href="#img3">&#60;<</a>
            <a href="#img1"><img src="imagenes/img4.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#img1">></a>
            
        </div>
        <a class="cerrar" href="">X</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>


body{
    background: #444;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: monospace;
}
h1{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;

}
/*Estilo de la galeria*/
.galeria{
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.galeria li{
    margin: 5px;
}
.galeria img{
    width:150px;
    height: 100px;
}

/*Estilos del Modal*/
.modal{
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.modal h3{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
.imagen{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
/*Estilos del modal*/
.modal{
display: none;
}

.modal:target{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgb(0,0,0,0.8);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.modal h3{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
.imagen{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.imagen a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.imagen a:nth-child(2){
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 2;
}

.imagen img{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 7px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.cerrar{
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
}```
````

Comment: ¿Qué es una *imagen tipo enlace*? ¿Podrías agregar una captura de pantalla?